# How to resize ScrollView when scaling inner AbsoluteLayout?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Working with Xamarin.Forms 5.0, all platforms (iOS, Android and UWP).

Inside a `ScrollView`, I've put an `AbsoluteLayout` with an image. When I scale the `AbsoluteLayout` the `ScrollView` doesn't resize according to the new size of the `AbsoluteLayout`/image.
As a result, when zooming in image gets "cropped" and when zooming out a lot of "empty margins" appear.

I've done a simple example showing this case in the simplest possible way:

MainPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ImageZoomExample.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <ScrollView Orientation="Both">
            <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="AbsLayoutCtrl">
                <Image Source="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dc/Grumpy_Cat_%2814556024763%29_%28cropped%29.jpg" />
            </AbsoluteLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <Slider x:Name="SliderCtrl" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Minimum="-4" Value="0" Maximum="5" ValueChanged="SliderCtrl_ValueChanged" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ImageZoomExample
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void SliderCtrl_ValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            double scale;
            if (e.NewValue < 0)
            {
                scale = 1 / (1 - e.NewValue);
            }
            else
            {
                scale = 1 + e.NewValue;
            }
            AbsLayoutCtrl.Scale = scale;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I resize properly the `ScrollView` when zooming in/out?

Comment: Please avoid putting tags in title when it is not necessary [Should I use tags in titles?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Yup. You're right, will take it into account next times.

Comment: You are resizing the AbsoluteLayout  not the scrollview, scrollview's size won't change as you did not change it. I'm not very clear about what you want to achieve, `when zooming in image gets "cropped"`, if the image is resize bigger than the screen size, it should be cropped. `when zooming out a lot of "empty margins"`, if it resize smaller than the background view, the empty margins are normal behaviors.

Comment: Yes, that part was a bit confusing.
When zooming in, the image (absoluteLayout, really) gets bigger than scrollview. Here's the point: When scrollview is then scrolled to the limit, at least one of the image edges won't be reachable. I want to reall all image limits in scrollview.
Tried to edit the question to clarify it, but I couldn't, sorry.
I'm seeing the point that AbsLayout doesn't really change size, so scrollview won't do so. It's a matter of viewports. Will try to add some translation to AbsLayout based on scaling and scroll gradients.

Comment: `When scrollview is then scrolled to the limit, at least one of the image edges won't be reachable.` This is what scrollview view do and it is normal behavior as I mentioned before.  `I want to read all image limits in scrollview.` So why you need a scrollview? A image view is enough and scrollview is use to scroll to see big images if needed.